# Tab not as extra alignment tab

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, automation

Is there a way to have LaTeX render the tabs in a tabular environment to determine the columns so that there is no further need for the ampersands & ?

Most of the time the columns only contain a word and I already align them in the source code with tabs. So it would come in handy to be able to leave the & out.

Comment: It's a *very bad* idea. Tabs are not set the same width across all editors, for one thing; even if they are set at 8 spaces, an entry more than 8 character long may require two tabs in another entry in the same column: chaos. Andrey's solution will catch those, but what about an empty cell, then?

Answer (score 14):

It certainly can be done, although I do not recommend using this in practice. The reason: you can't clearly tell where the cells' boundaries are anymore. However, if you are the only one editing the document, you are free to do what you like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=\active
  \gdef^^I{\@ifnextchar^^I{}{&}}
  \catcode`\^^M=\active
  \gdef^^M{\\}%
\endgroup
\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{%
  \catcode`\^^I=\active
  \catcode`\^^M=\active
  \begin{tabular}{#1}%
}{%
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Note two tabs after b
\begin{mytabular}{lll}
a   b       c
x   yyyyyyy z
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

As a bonus, the newline ends a row. If you want an empty cell, put `{}` in place of its content. If you want to split a row into several source lines, append `%` to them, except for the last one.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: It sounds like a new package ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
\newenvironment{tabbedtabular}[1]%
  {\catcode9=4\begin{tabular}{#1}}%
  {\end{tabular}\catcode9=10}
```

which puts the TAB character (ASCII 9) into category 4 (alignment, like & by default) before the environment, and back to category 10 (space) thereafter.

I'm not sure this is necessarily a good idea, though - it will make it very difficult to see whether, for instance, you've accidentally put two alignment characters in a row, or one in the wrong place. I'm sure others with more TeXpertise than me will chime in if this breaks anything else!

Comment: You don't need to restore the catcode because a LaTeX environment starts a group.

Comment: And `9` is not the tab character ;-)

Comment: @Andrey: yes, I saw that I didn't need to but I don't fully understand why: after all, I change the catcode /before/ beginning the group. And changing the catcode /inside/ the group doesn't work! (If this is too complicated to explain in a comment feel free to say so and I can ask it as a new question...)

Comment: @Andrey. The `9`-th ascii char is a tab. @Ant. Dunno why putting `\catcode9=4\relax` after `\begin{tabular}{#1}` wouldn't work (note the `\relax`, to make sure that the assignment is complete before TeX reads further). The "begin" and "end" code for `tabbedtabular` are run within a group, which has nothing to do with the group created by the tabular environment.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: I stand corrected.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Putting the `\catcode` assignment after `\begin{tabular}{#1}` performs it in the first cell of the alignment only (which is in an implicit group).

Comment: @egreg: yep, that'd explain it. Thanks. Now for bonus points, why don't I need to explicitly restore the catcode?

Comment: @Ant Because the environment forms a group and the catcode assignment will be undone automatically.